# Unable to parametrize SQl query in Java

Tags: java, sql

I need to parametrize a SQL query in Java using Fillo Object.

```
Fillo fillo=new Fillo();
        Connection connection=fillo.getConnection("C:\\Jeerdd\\Test.xlsx");
        String strQuery="Select * from Sheet1";
            Recordset recordset=connection.executeQuery(strQuery);

String y = "XYX"
while(recordset.next()){
            String dd = recordset.getField("ID");

        String strQuery1="Update Sheet1 Set Results =  'y'    where ID="+dd;
        //String strQuery1="Update Sheet1 Set Results="+y"and Time ="+xx" where ID="+dd;
        System.out.println(strQuery1);
        connection.executeUpdate(strQuery1);
    }
```

I want to parametrize the two values Results & ID  tried below but none of them is working.

```
 String strQuery1="Update Sheet1 Set Results =  'y'    where ID="+dd;

OR

String strQuery1="Update Sheet1 Set Results = "+y+"    where ID="+dd;
```

I don't want to use the Prepared statement. Can someone help me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: *I don't want to use the Prepared statement* - why not?  Also what error are you getting?

Comment: Plus you queries are strange.  You are basically updating all rows that you retrieve so just update **all** records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code in Fillo worked for me,

***"Update Sheet1 Set Results='"+field_Value+"' where ID='"+field_Name+"'";***

Below is the complete code

```
public static void statusUpdateTest(String field_Name, String field_Value) throws Throwable {


    Fillo fillo = new Fillo();
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        String excelPath = "C:\\Book\\Test.xlsx";
        connection = fillo.getConnection(excelPath);
        String strQuery = "Update Sheet1 Set Results='"+field_Value+"' where ID='"+field_Name+"'";
        connection.executeUpdate(strQuery);
        connection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e));
    } finally {
        Objects.requireNonNull(connection).close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, I don't even see the point of the first select.  Instead, just do a direct update on the entire table:

```
Fillo fillo = new Fillo();
Connection connection = fillo.getConnection("C:\\Jeerdd\\Test.xlsx");
String sql = "UPDATE Sheet1 SET Results = 'y'";
connection.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Comment: Iam getting an error as Cannot resolve method 'prepareStatement' in 'Connection' is any otherway to use bcoz iam using Fillo object.

Comment: What on earth is Fillo?  Edit your question with your stack trace

Comment: Actually the what i read Prepared statement is used with the  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/database", "postgres", "pswd"); but simple fillo iam using here is the link for that                     https://codoid.com/fillo/

Comment: @Learner I am also a learner on the `Fillo` library; I have never used or seen it before.  Since you don't require a prepared statement, you may call `executeUpdate()` directly on the Fillo connection object, q.v. the updated answer.

Comment: @Tim, Thank you i want to parametrize two things 1) Results & 2) ID  how to do that  can please hellp me.

Comment: @Learner I can't seem to find any references for using prepared statements with the Fillo library.  Maybe someone else can help you.

Comment: @Tim, with normal my question can't we parametrize variables in query ? ( iam also in learning )

Comment: What I'm telling you is, no, I don't see that the Fillo API exposes anything for prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think your approach is good, there is a more chance of sql injection in your case

You can simply use JPA Named Parameters like

```
String strQuery1="Update Sheet1 Set Results = :reults where ID= :id;

Query updateQuery = entityManager
                        .createNativeQuery(strQuery1);
                updateQuery.setParameter("reults", y);
                updateQuery.setParameter("id", dd);
                updateQuery.executeUpdate();
```